# Django formset error for ID "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices"

Tags: python, django

I am posting a formset in Django. The form on the client side is generated dynamically using a file uploaded by the user. I render it like this:

```
<form method="post" id="add3">
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% csrf_token %}
    <table id="forms">
     <tbody>
       {% for lst in result %}
       <input type="hidden" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id" value="{{ forloop.counter }}" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id">
       <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-expense" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-expense" value="{{lst.0}}"/>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-amount" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-amount" value="{{lst.1}}"/>
       </td>
       {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I get the following error on the server side when I receive the formset. Formset `is_valid` returns False and I get the error:

```
id: Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices
```

How can I fix this? What's the right way to pass an ID?
Note: I am updating management_form `total-forms` using Javascript. If that matters.